# Computing (near) optimal displacement tables

Tags: data-compression, sparse-matrices

Suppose we have a two-dimensional table $T$ with $r$ rows and $c$ columns that is sparse. Let $T[i][j]$ be the element at the $i$th row and $j$th column of $T$, with zero-based indexing.

We can compress $T[i][j]$ by putting all elements in a single 1D array $A$, and letting $A[D[i] + j] = T[i][j]$. Now with $D[i] = ci$ we have simply flattened the table.

But if the table is (very) sparse, we can do better than $D[i] = ri$. We can overlap rows where they're sparse! As an example we could have the table:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 6 &0 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 9\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5\\
\end{bmatrix}

Which we could compress like such:

$$A = [2, 6, 4, 3, 9, 1, 5]$$
$$D = [4,0,0,0,1]$$

Finally, to detect non-existing entries we also need a table of the same size as $A$ that tracks the source row of each entry:

$$C = [1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0, 4]$$

Only when $C[D[i] + j] = i$ we consider $A[D[i] + j] = T[i][j]$, otherwise we deduce $T[i][j] = 0$. We also assume that when $D[i] + j \geq |A|$ that the element is zero.

Now the question is, what  is a (near) optimal choice of $D$? We need to shift each row of $T$ so that each column only contains at most one non-zero element. A fast greedy method would be to handle each row in descending order of number of elements, and assign $D$ for that row in the first spot that doesn't cause a conflict.

But that isn't optimal. Is there another reasonably fast algorithm that provides better or optimal results?

Comment: Very interesting problem!  Consider the special case in which $c=2r+k$ and each row begins with a 1 followed by $r-1$ zeros, and ends with $r-1$ zeros followed by a 1, with $k$ "meat" entries in the middle, and the goal is to see whether we can fit all of the rows into an $A$ of size $3r+k-1$: I think this retains the essential "hardness" of the problem, and from this perspective the problem becomes one of *ordering* the rows (since each row must then have a unique offset in the range $[0, r-1]$) -- but I can't think of a reduction from Hamiltonian Path.

Comment: @j_random_hacker While a reduction would be interesting in it's own right, I wouldn't be surprised if it's NP complete whatsoever, and already am surrendering myself to approximations :)

Comment: Ah :)  If $c$ is small, say, < 30, then you could fix a tentative size $s$ for $A$, do dynamic programming on subsets of column positions in $O(2^ssr)$ time, all this inside a binary search on $s$ to find the minimal size with a solution (this adds another $\log c$ factor).

Comment: @j_random_hacker I expect the tables to be roughly 256 x c, with c being anywhere from ~15 up to 1000.

Comment: I would probably go with beam search on the non-tiny instances for this -- basically, a version of branch and bound that lets you trade off solution quality for time.  Rather than picking as the row to place next the one that has the most nonzeros, I think you would do better by placing the one whose best placement increases the width of the current partial solution by the most, but I could easily be wrong about that.

Comment: One more thought: Is the "width" (span from leftmost nonzero element to rightmost nonzero element) of each row typically small?  If so, you can look for ways to combine small numbers of rows into (near-)perfect sub-solutions, namely intervals containing no (or few) nonzeros.  These can then be concatenated in any order.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Not necessarily.